# !empty fails on image upload field check

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have a form with about 10 fields, the very last is the imageUpload field, it is *not* a required field. I am trying to do an exif check on the file ONLY if the field is populated. But as the title states !empty fails when checking if it is populated and it just continues like there is a file there, which of course throws a warning. `Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in`

```
if(!empty($_FILES['imageUpload'])){
    $allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
    $detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name']);
    $isImage = !in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes);
    if(!empty($isImage)){
        $errormsg[] = 'This is not a valid image file.';
    }
}
```

Here is a var_dump of the field. `array(1) { ["imageUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } }`

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: $_FILES['imageUpload'] is not empty, it contains bunch of empty strings ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0)

Comment: As he said. Try checking empty on one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name'])){
    $allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
    $detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name']);
    $isImage = !in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes);
    if(!empty($isImage)){
        $errormsg[] = 'This is not a valid image file.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that works, but explain to me why it wouldn't work the other way, the values of the $_FILE array were all 0.

Comment: That means that the !empty check sees nested arrays inside the $_FILES['imageUpload']. Conclusion: $_FILES['imageUpload'] is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `tmp_name` of the file:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name'])) {
    // do stuff
}
```